# How do I print all current Play2 configs?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, typesafe-stack, typesafe-config

I have `val config = Play.current.configuration` and I want to get a `Map[String, String]` of all current configs key and their string values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.entrySet.toMap.mapValues(_.render)`